# Is it possible to get an access to variables captured in a closure associated with a function instance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, reflection, closures, anonymous-function

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
function getFunction(x) {
    var closureMember = x;

    return function() {
        return closureMember * 2;
    };
}

var f = getFunction(5);
```

Here a call to `getFunction` creates a closure containing the member `closureMember`, returns an anonymous function referencing this closure, and assigns it to the variable `f`. If I invoke the anonymous function, its code will be executed and the member `closureMember` in the closure will be actually accessed.

JavaScript allows me to invoke the method `toString` on an anonymous function that returns the textual representation of its code. In this case, the representation will contain the name of `closureMember` without giving any access to the actual variable (note that it can exists in multiple instances if `getFunction` was invoked multiple times).

*Question:*
Does JavaScript provide any reflection capabilities that would allow to analyze/modify the structure and content of closures associated with function instances at runtime?

Comment: Sure, add properties to the returned function, and use them. http://jsfiddle.net/r4Q3j/

Comment: The question is about if such a feature exists, not about possible workarounds involving modification of code returning a function.

Comment: @Ian I believe the OP is looking for access to `closureMember` without modifying `getFunction`.

Comment: @Լ.Ƭ. I don't understand what you mean by "workaround". Maybe I'm misunderstanding "reflection capabilities". What do you want to be able to do?

Comment: @bfavaretto I don't see how that was in the OP, but I'm sure that was the intent :) Like my last comment, I guess I'm misunderstanding "reflection capabilities". Nonetheless, it was just an attempt/comment

Comment: Quick answer: **no**, that's not possible.

Comment: @Ian _Reflection_ refers to programmatically accessing internal aspects of programs, without requiring changes to the program itself. What the OP is looking for is a way to directly access the mapping between closed variables and their current values in a closure. But JS doesn't have this.

Comment: i agree with bfavaretto that it's not directly possible via reflection. but you could replace all the "closureMember" of the toString with the value you want it to have and and invoke new Function(resultingString) with the resultingString and get so a new function that has the same characteristics as the gottenFunction (only that the memberValue is set to what you want)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's exactly what you want but the next code works fine.

```
function getFunction(x) {
    var closureMember = x;

    return function() {
        return closureMember * 2;
    };
}

function changeClosure(x, closure){ 
    var closureMember = x; 
    return eval("(" + closure.toString() + ")");
}

var f = getFunction(5);
var g = changeClosure(42, f);

g();
```